# Overleaf reporting error in Minted-Code

Tags: overleaf, minted

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted}

\newminted[vuecode]{javascript}{
frame=lines,
framesep=2mm,
baselinestretch=1.2,
breaklines,
fontsize=\footnotesize,
linenos,
rulecolor=blue,
label=Vue Code
}

\begin{document}
\begin{vuecode}
<script>
export default {
  props: {
    to: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
  },
  methods: {
    navigate() {
      this.$router.push(this.to);
    },
  },
};
</script>
\end{vuecode}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I have the Code as shown above as minimal working example on Overleaf.
This code compiles, but shows this error, which sometimes just magically disappears.

I guess the code-check of Overleaf doesn't work here properly. Can i resolve this somehow?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please provide a minimal working example that tells us which packages you use and what the exact definition for the `vuecode` environment is.

Comment: Thank you! I understand, that the PDF is compiled correcty and this is just a syntax warning issued by the editor? Then you should probably just ignore this warning. But you could ask the Overleaf support, as it should be considered an Overleaf bug but not a bug in (La)TeX.

Comment: In Overleaf, you can put any code that should not be checked between `%%begin novalidate` and `%%end novalidate`. See: https://de.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/Code_Check#Code_Check_Limitations

Comment: Thank you so much! `novalidate` has solved my problem. The code still appears green, due to the `$` sign (which doesn't bother me), but at least, the `unexpected close` is gone!